# Spark Scala - Data type for columns representing times without dates (hhmm format)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have seen that there are types `TimestampType` and `DateType` for representing dates and timestamps like this:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|          timestamp|      date|
+-------------------+----------+
|2020-07-01 00:00:00|2020-07-01|
+-------------------+----------+
```

I was wondering how to deal in Spark (Scala) with columns representing day times in `hhmm` format.

For instance these columns:

- `deptime`: actual departure time (e.g. **1345**)
- `arrtime`: actual arrival time (e.g. **1545**)

In this case: a plane departs at `13:45` and arrives at its destination at `15:45`

I don't know if there is a specific type to deal with this columns or if I have to treat them as integers or maybe as strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the structure of a type and how it gets printed are two completely different things. `Timestamp` serializes the data in a universally agreed format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and also comes with constructors that is able to parse strings formatted in such a way to a Timestamp object. If you simply want time to be printed as `hhmm` you can define a class and overwrite the serialization as such. If you want your data to actually have that shape, you have no choice but to represent them using one of the built in primitives

Comment: @sinanspd I am going to apply several machine learning models to the data, so I don't know what type would be the most suitable in this case. I feel that treating hours as integers is not a good choice at all, what do you think?

Comment: One of the most common time formats is Epoch which is `Long`. So I don't know why you think integer is not suitable. Even if you build an object, one of the properties representing hours will be an integer. That being said, this information will be useless without date. If a flight takes 12 hours and it departs at 13:00 and lands at 13:00 the next day, regardless of what you are doing, I am almost certain something will go wrong. People who built Java's time library and standards knew what they were doing. I should just use one of them